# Solving linear matrix equation

Tags: matrices, matrix-theory, matrix-equations

Given matrices $A, B, C' \in \Bbb R^{2 \times 6}$, where $'$ denotes matrix transposition, and matrix $L \in \Bbb R^{2 \times 2}$, how can one solve the following linear matrix equation in $X \in \Bbb R^{2 \times 2}$?

$$ ACXC'A' - BCXC'B' = L $$

$X$ is a covariance matrix that should be positive definite or semidefinite. Is there any standard solution to ensure getting correct values?

Comment: @markvs I don't think you can assume that $X$ is diagonal, are you sure? If you're planning to change basis (with an unknown matrix $Q$), then you won't know the expression of the coefficients in that basis.

Comment: According to the author: yes X is normally a diagonal matrix.

Comment: here are the values of the first iteration: **L** = [-8  1.0231e-14 ;  1.0230e-14 -3.0184e-07 ],  **C** =   [0.5000    0;   0    0.5000;  1.0000     0;  0    1.0000 ;  1.0000    0; 0    1.0000] ; **B** = [0.1964    0.9805   0    0    0    0;  -1.9046e-04    3.8145e-05     0   0   0   0] ;                                             **A** =[    0.1964  0.9805  0  0 0  0; -1.9046e-04    3.8145e-05  0  0  0  0]                                                **Note that, when I compute L it is shown too closely to be symmetric.**

Answer (score 4):

This is just a system of 4 linear equations in the 4 unknown entries of $X$. Just write down those four equations and solve it. For generic $A,B,C$, it will be nonsingular, so there is going to be only one solution $X\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$. If that matrix is not positive semidefinite, there is little you can do apart from relaxing the problem somehow; for instance you could look for the closest positive semidefinite matrix to the solution, or the positive semidefinite matrix that minimizes the residual. The case in which there are an infinite number of solutions is probably trickier, but I would not start assuming that until you verify that it is the case.

If you want to introduce some notation to formalize the process, you can introduce [Kronecker products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Matrix_equations), but even without them you can just write down the equations and do everything by hand in the $2\times 2$ case.

There is an [algorithm by Hammarling](https://academic.oup.com/imajna/article-abstract/2/3/303/763034) to compute solutions to similar matrix equations by computing the Cholesky factor of $X$ directly; this idea ensures automatically that a positive semidefinite $X$ is produced. But

1. As far as I can see the case of your matrix equation does not appear in the paper (even after giving a better name to $AC$ and $BC$).
2. Your equation is not guaranteed to have a positive semidefinite solution $X$, not even when $L$ is positive definite; for instance take $AC=I$ and $BC=2I$.
3. This paper and algorithm might be overkill, especially if you have a $2\times 2$ case.

Comment: First of all, I treated it as a 4 linear equation and implemented it in MatLab regarding its a part of a system that is running for a certain period, but this isn't work and lead to diverging while running since L is somehow (system details) related to the X matrix from the previous iteration update.

Comment: I should mention that in implementing on MatLab, I get no solution if I supposed X as a diagonal matrix, otherwise suppose X as the symmetric matrix led to not always having a solution and I should, in this case, use the value of the previous iteration. but there are no issues when I suppose X as the non-symmetric matrix.
but as I mentioned above it leads to diverge

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you are drowning in a glass of water.

Putting $AC=U\in M_2$ and $BC=V\in M_2$, we obtain

(*) $UXU^T-VXV^T=L$ in $M_2$.

If $X$ is a symmetric solution of (*), then $L$ too.
For generic $U,V,L$, there is a unique solution; then if, conversely, $L$ is generic symmetric, then the solution $X$ too.

In particular, there are $3$ independent linear relations linking the $3$ unknowns $x_{1,1},x_{1,2},x_{2,2}$ and not $4$.

If you want that your symmetric solution is $\geq 0$, then of course $U,V,L$ must satisfy additional relations so that $x_{1,1}\geq 0,x_{2,2}\geq 0,\det(X)\geq 0$; these conditions are easy to write since (*) is linear wrt $X$.

On the other hand,

The generic (*) admits a $\geq 0$ symmetric solution with probability $\approx 0.21$; for comparison, a random symmetric $2\times 2$ matrix is $\geq 0$ with probability $\approx 0.11$.

Comment: thank you for your contribution,
Let me tell you another piece of info why does this equation make me not sure about the way of solving it, this equation actually is a recursive equation which means:
A(k)CX(k)C′A(k)′−B(k)CX(k)C′B(k)′=L(k)
and in each iteration, L(k) is being calculated from the previous calculated X(k-1),  in other words L(k) = f(X(k-1))

Comment: when I tried to solve this linear equation as a normal linear equation the result is being increased and make the solution divergence iteration by iteration. 
starting from initial values for L getting X by this equation then calculate L depending on previous X (L getting bigger and so on...)
that's why I am suspesiouse of solving it as normal especially since I am dealing with a covariance matrix.
and yes, I can say about my L matrix is symmetric.

Comment: so now I can also be sure that nothing is wrong in the way of solving my equation, depending on your answers, right?
but I can't find the reason for the divergence!

Comment: @Wijdan Mt , if $A,B$  vary during your iteration, then  you have to write in your post all the details of the iteration. Otherwise we can't conclude anything. Add this information in the body of your question.